# .net 6.0 Nlog Custom AspNetLayoutRenderer

Tags: .net-6.0, nlog, webapi

I'm trying to add a custom aspnetLayoutRenderer.

I've copied the standard AspNetTraceIdentifierLayoutRenderer and renamed it to MyyAspNetTraceIdentifierLayoutRenderer.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ASP.NET Request TraceIdentifier.
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutRenderer("my-aspnet-traceidentifier")]
    [ThreadSafe]
    public class MyAspNetTraceIdentifierLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var httpContext = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            builder.Append(LookupTraceIdentifier(httpContext));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore the System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id value (AspNetCore3 uses ActivityId by default)
        /// </summary>
        public bool IgnoreActivityId { get; set; }

        private string LookupTraceIdentifier(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (IgnoreActivityId)
                return httpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            else
                return System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id ?? httpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        }
    }
```

Then i add this to my NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Warn" internalLogFile="c:\logs\My.WebApi.Project\nlog-internal.log">

  <!-- optional, add some variables
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="c:\logs"/>
  <variable name="namespace" value="My.WebApi.Project"/>

  <extensions>
    <add prefix="custom" assembly="My.WebApi.Project" />
  </extensions>
  <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" 
      layout="${longdate}|${level:fixedLength=True:padding=5:padCharacter= :upperCase=True}|${aspnet-TraceIdentifier:ignoreActivityId=true}|${custom.my-aspnet-traceidentifier:ignoreActivityId=true}|${uppercase:${aspnet-user-identity}}|${message} ${onexception:${newline} ${exception:format=tostring:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5}"
      fileName="${var:logDirectory}\${var:namespace}\${var:namespace}.log"
    />

  </targets>
    
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fError" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

The problem is that I never see anything in the output file.

I even put a break point in the "DoAppend" method and run the application in debug mode but it never gets hit.

Can anyone help?

Comment: First verify that the constructor for the custom layout-renderer is called. Also notice that `DoAppend` is only called when there is an active HttpRequest with a valid HttpContext. Also a good idea to enable `throwConfigExceptions="true"` and checking the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) when [troubleshooting logging in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting)